# Ubuntu: how to mass download a field from multiple websites?

Tags: php, database, scripting, curl, download

I **do** have permission to do this.

I've got a website with about 250 pages from which I need to download the 'product descriptions' and 'product images'. How do I do it? I'd like to get the data out into a CSV, so that I can put it in a DB table.  Could someone point me to a good tutorial to get started on this?  I should be using cURL, right?

So far, I got this from another stackoverflow page, [How do I transfer wget output to a file or DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702535/how-do-i-transfer-wget-output-to-a-file-or-db):

```
curl somesite.com | grep sed etc | sed -e '/^(.*)/INSERT tableName (columnName) VALUES (\1)/' |psql dbname
```

And I created this, which sucks, to get the images:

```
#!/bin/bash

lynx --source "www.site.com"|cut -d\" -f8|grep jpg|while read image
do
wget "www.site.com/$image"
done
```

by watching this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMXzoHTTvi0.

Comment: If you have permission, wouldn't you have the files locally (i.e. not need to access them as web sites with curl?)

Comment: If you want cumbersome code, then yes the fiddly curl API is indeed preferrable to PHPs HttpRequest, PEAR Http_Request or Zend_Http. If it's a one time download thing a simple `wget -p http://example.org/prodcuts/*` might be easier.

Comment: Perl's `WWW::Mechanize` comes to mind. Probably a better tool for the job than PHP (mainly because CPAN is awesome)

Comment: @Fosco: No.  @Mario: Is it possible to go by the DIV or something using wget?

Comment: @Fosco: If the data are publicly available you are allowed to do that.

Comment: Nope. It only downloads files. You need to postprocess it using phpQuery or QueryPath or [another HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html) which simplify this very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do what's called screen scraping.

Here are some links to get you started:

- http://www.bradino.com/php/screen-scraping/
- http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/easy-screen-scraping-in-php-simple-html-dom-library-simplehtmldom-398/
- http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4606.html
- http://www.google.com/search?q=screen+scraping+php

Comment: I'd like to do it from command line, and I was under the impression that 'screen scraping' was visual.  I'll give these links a look and get back to you, though.  Thank you, Byron.

Comment: Maybe it's called 'recursive fetching'?

Comment: I've reviewed the links and found that many of them lead to code that returns errors.  The first link's first code block returns invalid token errors, for example.  I hope that you can create a good example, somehow. :)  I found one, and I would like to link it in my own answer.  I welcome you to attempt to come back first, though.  Thank you.