# How do I transfer wget output to a file or DB?

Tags: bash, curl, pipe, wget, cut

I'm trying to use a small script to download a field from multiple pages.  For one thing, I'm only able to get it from one page..., but the real problem I'm having is that I don't know how to hand the output off to a database table?  How can I take the output from curl/lynx|grep (which is going to be all the list items) and move it, list item by list item, to a table in my DB or to a CSV where it will be ready for import to the DB?

```
#!/bin/bash

lynx --source "http://www.thewebsite.com"|cut -d\" -f8|grep "<li>"
```

The database I would connect to would be a MySQL database.  We could call the dummy table "listTable".  Please, try to stick to bash?  I'm not allowed to compile on the server I'm using, and I can't seem to get curl to work with PHP.  Anyway, I'm thinking I need to make a variable and then systematically pass the contents of the variable to the database, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like awk, sed or perl to create INSERT statements, then pipe that to your sql client (psql or mysql).

Comment: Tassos, would you please give me some sample to show what the piping would look like or how it is formed?

Comment: Basically, like the other guy said: curl whatever.com | ./script_name, right?

Comment: Well, it really depends on what you want to do - could be something like `curl somesite.com | grep sed etc | sed -e '/^(.*)/INSERT tableName (columnName) VALUES (\1)/' |psql dbname`.

Comment: I'm going to mess around with this for a while.  Very helpful, I think.  A strong push in the right direction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a Python script which reads everything from the stdin an puts it into the database and do something like:

`curl http://www.google.com | ./put_to_db.py`